# Flask list of fields gets the data inside just the first element

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the data from a form that is made dynamically using Flask and WTForms. To do that I've created a list that gets populated when a user opens the link, but when I try to get the data from html I only get the data from the first element of the list.
Forms:

```
class Details_Form(FlaskForm):
    preschool_groups = []
    classes = []
    continue_button = SubmitField('Continuă')

    def appeend_group(self):
        preschool_details = Preschool_Details()
        self.preschool_groups.append(preschool_details)

    def appeend_class(self, choices):
        class_details = Classes_Details()
        class_details.class_type.choices = choices
        self.classes.append(class_details)

class Preschool_Details(FlaskForm):
    group_name = StringField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    group_size = IntegerField('', validators=[DataRequired()])

class Classes_Details(FlaskForm):
    class_name = StringField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    class_size = IntegerField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    class_type = SelectField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Routes:

```
@app.route('/detalii-scoala/<school>/<groups>/<classes>', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def school_details_page(school, groups, classes):
    groups = int(groups)
    classes = int(classes)
    details_form = Details_Form()
    details_form.classes.clear()
    details_form.preschool_groups.clear()

    school_db_item = db.session.query(School).join(User, User.id == School.psychologist_id).filter(User.id == current_user.id).filter(School.school==school).first()
    education_types = school_db_item.education_type.split(',')

    for _ in range(groups):
        details_form.appeend_group()
    for _ in range(classes):
        details_form.appeend_class(education_types)
    
    if details_form.continue_button.data and details_form.validate_on_submit():
        for preschool_details in details_form.preschool_groups:
            group = Group(name=preschool_details.group_name.data, number_of_pupils=preschool_details.group_size.data, school_id=school_db_item.id)      
            db.session.add(group)

        for class_details in details_form.classes:
            print(class_details.class_name.data)
            c = Classes(name=class_details.class_name.data, number_of_students=class_details.class_size.data, class_type=class_details.class_type.data, school_id=school_db_item.id)   
            db.session.add(c)

        db.session.commit()
        
        details_form.classes.clear()
        details_form.preschool_groups.clear()
        flash('Detaliile au fost inregistrate')
        return redirect(url_for('session_page'))

    return render_template('detalii-scoala.html', details_form=details_form)
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ details_form.hidden_tag() }}
    <table>
        
        {% for preschool in details_form.preschool_groups %}
        <tr>
            <td><p>
                {{ preschool.group_name(class_="form-control") }}<br>
                {% for error in preschool.group_name.errors %}
                <span class="error">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p></td>
            <td><p>
                {{ preschool.group_size(class_="form-control") }}<br>
                {% for error in preschool.group_size.errors %}
                <span class="error">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Denumire clasă</td>
            <td>Nr. elevi înscrişi</td>
            <td>Ciclul</td>
        </tr>
        {% for class in details_form.classes %}
        <tr>
            <td><p>
                {{ class.class_name(class_="form-control") }}<br>
                {% for error in class.class_name.errors %}
                <span class="error">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p></td>
            <td><p>
                {{ class.class_size(class_="form-control") }}<br>
                {% for error in class.class_size.errors %}
                <span class="error">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p></td>
            <td><p>
                {{ class.class_type(class_="form-control") }}<br>
                {% for error in class.class_type.errors %}
                <span class="error">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p>{{ details_form.continue_button(class_="btn btn-primary") }}</p>
</form>
```

Front end works, the only problem is when I try to add the data from thee form in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that HTML fields were having the same name. To solve that I used `request.form.getlist('name)` to create the lists